# how to check if a list contains a specific string or not in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to search if a list contains a string or not. The following code does not compile.

```
list= []         
list.append("item1")         
list.append("item2")         
list.append("item3")     

if 'item1' in list
    print "yes"  
else  
    print "no"
```

Error:

```
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py", line 117, in compile  
    raise py_exc  
py_compile.PyCompileError:   File "prog.py", line 6  
    if 'item1' in command  
                          ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need colons after [if and else statements](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Comment: since `list` is a builtin, you should not use it as a variable name.  prefer `lst` or `seq` instead, for simple options (though you should usually be able to come up with something more descriptive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a colon after your if statement/else statement.

Also, I believe in python when you use print it has to go like print(*MESSAGE*). Edit: Using brackets is the new way in python3.

Try this:

```
list= []         
list.append("item1")         
list.append("item2")         
list.append("item3")     

if 'item1' in list:
    print("yes")
else: 
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for if statement in Python is

```
 if *condition*:
        statements
 else:
        statements
```

In your code you miss a colon(:) in if and else part.

```
list= []         
list.append("item1")         
list.append("item2")         
list.append("item3")

print True if "item1" in list else False
```

Comment: or just `print 'item1' in list`